# "document.getElementById" is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am programming a set of traffic lights using HTML and JavaScript and I have run into a problem. I created a button which should change a line of text on the website to be a number, however whenever it is clicked it does nothing. I assume this is a problem with the `document.getElementById` script as I don't think it could be anything else. Here's my code:

```
<p id="dummy">PLACEHOLDER</p>

<script>
var imgArray = ["img0", "img1", "img2", "img3"];

imgArray[0] = new Image(300, 150);
imgArray[0].src = "Assets/TrafficLightRedLight.jpg";
imgArray[1] = new Image(300, 150);
imgArray[1].src = "Assets/TrafficLightRedAmberLight.jpg";
imgArray[2] = new Image(300, 150);
imgArray[2].src = "Assets/TrafficLightAmberLight.jpg";
imgArray[3] = new Image(300, 150);
imgArray[3].src = "Assets/TrafficLightGreenLight.jpg";

var counter = 0;

function count(counter){
    if (counter =! 3){
         counter + 1;
    }   
    else{
        counter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = counter;
}

</script>

<button type="button"
onclick="count">Test_Function</button>
```

Comment: perhaps to try onclick="count()" instead?

Comment: "as I don't think it could be anything else"... usually a sign that it's *definitely* something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four problems:

1. You need to *call* `count` in your handler:

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="count()">Test_Function</button>
   ```
2. `counter =! 3` should be `counter != 3`, otherwise you're setting it to `false`
3. `counter + 1` doesn't do anything. Use `counter += 1` or `counter++`
4. Don't use `counter` as a parameter - you'd only modify the local copy.

All the above fixes:

```html
<p id="dummy">PLACEHOLDER</p>

<script>
  var imgArray = ["img0", "img1", "img2", "img3"];
  var counter = 0;

  imgArray[0] = new Image(300, 150);
  imgArray[0].src = "Assets/TrafficLightRedLight.jpg";
  imgArray[1] = new Image(300, 150);
  imgArray[1].src = "Assets/TrafficLightRedAmberLight.jpg";
  imgArray[2] = new Image(300, 150);
  imgArray[2].src = "Assets/TrafficLightAmberLight.jpg";
  imgArray[3] = new Image(300, 150);
  imgArray[3].src = "Assets/TrafficLightGreenLight.jpg";


  function count() {
    if (counter != 3) {
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = counter;
  }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="count()">Test_Function</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how much of a headache this was gving me. At least now I know for the future.